# Will the Samsung Fascinate work without a battery?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, battery, samsung-fascinate

Can I use a Samsung Fascinate with no battery powered only by the power cable?

*(I'm assuming this is a handset specific question, but let me know if I'm wrong and the answer applies to all Android handsets and I'll edit the question to be more general)*

Comment: It's definitely handset-specific, unless Google has some sort of bizarre requirement about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  I have another SGS model and it works with no battery for a second, as long as the battery's in when you start it up, but quickly shuts off.

Comment: Any way you could try it without the battery all together and let me know?  I have the opportunity to buy one cheap with no battery or battery cover which would make a great gps/media player for the car but I don't want to have to buy a replacement battery.

Comment: Yeah it won't boot without the battery.  I got a second battery for myself on eBay for $15 new though, no issues with it.  I also have to amend my answer -- I just tried my phone again and while it stayed on with the battery out, it shut off when I started an app.

Comment: Same guy is still selling them: http://cgi.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItem&item=300453894480&ssPageName=ADME:X:AAQ:AU:1123